# ¿Cómo puedo retrasar el evento de un observable en las 2 primeras ejecuciones?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, pipe

se que la función `delay()` permite retrasar todos los eventos pero yo solo necesito que me retrase los 2 primeros por ejemplo intente esto:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/k4xb43?file=index.ts

```
const clicks = fromEvent(document, "click");
const delayedClicks = clicks.pipe(
  take(2),
  delay(500)
); // each click emitted after 1 second
delayedClicks.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

retrasa la ejecución pero luego me bloque todos los eventos, como podría retrasarlo únicamente en las 2 primeras ejecuciones?

Comment: Y si usas delayWhen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora que me di el tiempo de responder te muestro un ejemplo por si aún no lo solucionaste o por si alguna otra persona se tope con algo similar. Lo que podrías hacer es utilizar el operador delayWhen junto a un contador o dependiendo de lo que estés realizando usar una variable o función y en base al resultado ejecutar el delay por ejemplo:

```
private stop$ = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let contador = 0;
    const clicks = fromEvent(document, "click");
    const delayedClicks = clicks
      .pipe(
        tap(() => contador++),
        takeUntil(this.stop$),
        delayWhen(x => contador>2 ? interval(0) : interval(500))
      )
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x+"Contador:" + contador));
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stop$.next();
    this.stop$.complete();
  }
```

El operador delayWhen retrasa la emisión en un lapso de tiempo determinado, y con el operador tap() interceptas cada emisión del observable y ejecutas una función, se puede usar como depurador en los observables para verificar errores o realizar alguna acción o efecto secundario. Saludos!! :)